# How to Run a Batch File from Java Code onclicking a Button

Tags: java

On clicking a button in a jsp page, I want to run a batch file. I wrote this code to execute a batch file inside a method, but it's not working. Plz help me out.

```
public String scheduler() {
    String result=SUCCESS;  
    try {

        Process p =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start.bat", null, new File("C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.0\\bin\\start"));

        System.out.println("manual scheduler for application.."+p);
    } catch(Exception e) {  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code,

```
batFile.setExecutable(true);

//Running bat file
Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(PATH_OF_PARENT_FOLDER_OF_BAT_SCRIPT_FILE+File.separator+batFile.getName());                                                              
byte []buf = new byte[300];
InputStream errorStream = exec.getErrorStream();
errorStream.read(buf);                              
logger.debug(new String(buf));
int waitFor = exec.waitFor();
if(waitFor==0) {
    System.out.println("BAT script executed properly");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1485791/1140338), the following code should work (just remove the `cmd /c`):

```
public String scheduler() {
    String result=SUCCESS;  
    try {

        File f = new File("C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.0\\bin\\start")
        Process p =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("start.bat", null, f);

        System.out.println("manual scheduler for application.."+p);
    } catch(Exception e) {   
    }
}
```

Comment: hi mvieghofer thanx for replying..but this sol is not working. Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start scheduler1.bat") is working.but cmd by default taking path where weblogic batch file is stored.the path address i m giving through code is not working.

Comment: cmd taking default address E:\bea\user_projects\domain\base_domain.which is startWeblogic batch file address.i think app is running on server thats why its taking server batch file default address...confused.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear here whether you just want to run a bat file or you want to wait for it to run.

// the location where bat file is located is required eg. K:/MyPath/MyBat.bat in my case
 // If bat file is in classpath then you can provide direct bat file name MyBat.bat

```
 **Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime() ;
 Process batRunningProcess= rt.exec("cmd /c   K:/MyPath/MyBat.bat");**
```

// This is to wait for process to complete
 //if process is completed then value will be 0

```
 **final int exitVal =  lawTab_Indexer.waitFor();**
```

// This line is not required if you just want to run a bat file and dont want to wait for it to get completed.

Comment: i want to run a batch file from struts 2 application,onclicking a submit option.onclicking submit i m calling a method,which is given above.but function is not working.